# Free time-tracking/timesheet software (like bugzilla/trac but for timesheets)

Tags: untagged

Are there any free tools, preferably web-based, which you can use for timesheets? I'm thinking in the same vein as tools like bugzilla, but providing standard timesheet tools - entering work done each day on different tasks, etc.

Answer (score 1):

I've used [Toggl](http://www.toggl.com) is the past to do timesheets, and found it ok for what it was.

Probably not quite what you want, because it is a hosted service rather than running off your own infrastructure...

Answer (score 1):

[Redmine](http://www.redmine.org) can keep track of time expent on each issue.
You can get a timesheet-like interface using the [bulk time entry plugin](http://www.redmine.org/attachments/1116/bulk_time_entry.png).

Comment: It looks good, but I cannot see a place I can enter time in their demo... I can enter estimated and current completion % when CREATING an issue, but no way to add further time after! Am I missing something obvious?

Comment: That probably has to do with the demo site allowing anonymous comments and issues. Anonymous user gets a reduced interface when updating issues.

The screenshot show the form to update issues on our internal redmine:
http://img.skitch.com/20091107-pyppg924rej7ckiwajj7ae6jf5.jpg

Answer (score 0):

I've used [SlimTimer](http://slimtimer.com/) on a few projects and I'm liking it allot.

You have to get use to how they use tagging to organize tasks. But it ends up being more flexible. Kind of like labeling in Gmail.

They also have a small timer window that I wrap in a Google Chrome 'app'. Feels just like an application.